# Books Recommended for Beginner SharePoint architect

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, architecture, windows-server

I am a recent graduate and got a job as a junior SharePoint developer few months ago. For the last few months, I have been working on SharePoint development, e.g. webparts, .Net Forms, K2, Lists, Features, for Moss and a little bit for SharePoint 2010 as well...

Now because I made a future plan to become a SharePoint architect, I am not sure what way I need to follow to become what I want to, As there are so many things to learn in SharePoint, I am looking for Book or a series of Book that will help me gain knowledge as a SharePoint Architect has.

I am a bit confused with SharePoint architecture as well, like If I want to develop a new SharePoint Solution, What hardware e.g. Servers, Do I need + Software, e.g. We use .Net Forms, but are they better then using Info-Path forms ?

Oh yes just remembered that What areas do I have to look into to become a SharePoint Architect.

Thanks (I know its not a Coding question but I think its somehow related to Programming so please dont close it.. Cheers)

Comment: I've converted this to a Community Wiki. And don't worry about it not being a coding question - IT and Architecture questions are welcome - it's not StackOverflow ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IT architecture is something you mature into with experience. Just focus on developing good solutions, and build those skills. Always take opportunities to work on projects that cover different areas - for example, if you've built lots of web parts, work on a project that uses BCS or InfoPath, or Excel Services. Always pay attention to the hardware & infrastructure guys - ask questions, try to get involved.

Technologies and techniques can be learned in books, but they are always to accomplish *specific problems*. Architecture is about communicating and understanding the business problem, and understanding the entire possible solution space through experience working with it.

Over time, making the shift to architecture will be as natural as taking the next step forward walking.

Comment: I'll second Rex's answer but also provide a few resources I think will help you on the way: 1. Join a SharePoint users' group or start on if there isn't one in your area. 2. Essential SharePoint 2010: Overview, Governance, and Planning (Addison-Wesley Microsoft Technology Series). 3. Microsoft® Office SharePoint® Server 2007 Best Practices. 4. Designing Solutions for Microsoft SharePoint 2010: Making the right architecture and implementation decisions (Patterns & Practices)

Comment: cheers guys nice 1, yeah I am trying my best :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether my answer is the correct answer or not for you. But my goal is also exactly same as yours :)
Few things really help me a lot. So below are my approach to learn sharepoint

- Go through MSDN, Technet each day. MSDN and Technet contains almost
  all the concepts that you are gonna use in day to day life.
- Go through blogs of Microsoft MVPs as these are the people who
  dissect    the code very much.
- Start blogging and twweting. These    will    motivate u a lot and
  as u know sharing is caring blogging    will    improve technical
  skill as well as you try to share what u    have    achieved and
  other people can take your help when required.
- Participate in the sharepoint communities and be in touch with
  other sharepoint developers and architects.
- If possible try to     attend sharepoint sessions held by MVPs.
  e.g. Sharepoint Saturday,       Teched, etc.